# Remove node_modules folder after building

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

is it dangerous to keep the folder node_modules on the prod server after building the app.js? Or should I delete the folder after building?. The node_modules folder is not public.

Comment: i don't think it's necessary, or desirable, to remove it

Comment: Generally node_modules folder is excluded from version control. So when you push the app to production server via version control then node_modules folder is not there on production server. It's not required unless you want to build the assets.

Answer (score 2):

If your build process uses webpack (or equivalent) to generate the distributable js, you dont need to keep node_modules at all.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, dfgdghjezfghfgdh!

**Generally speaking, as the folder is not public, you don't need to worry about it existing in the file system.** Depending on how your project is built you might even require it in your production environment as well.

Hope this helped.